# Proof of Weak Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, proof-explanation, hahn-banach-theorem

I am going through Differential and Riemannian Manifolds by Serge Lang. In Proposition 2.3 it is stated a weak version of the Hahn-Banach theorem. It is stated as follows

> Let $\mathbf{E}$ be a Banach Space and $x\neq0$ an element of $\mathbf{E}$. Then there exists a linear continuous map $\lambda:\mathbf{E}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(x)\neq 0$

Now, the proof is not given in the text, nevertheless a small explanation is given, it is the following:

> One constructs $\lambda$ by Zorn's lemma, supposing that $\lambda$ is defined on
>   some subspace, and having a bounded norm. One then extends $\lambda$ to the
>   subspace generated by one additional element, without increasing the
>   norm.

From here I take that $\lambda$ is first supposed to exist, which makes no sense to me. Maybe I am not understanding the explanation at all, so I ask if anyone could give some insight or make a mora detailed explanation of this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to give a brief proof sketch.

You first define $\lambda: \mathbb{R}x \to \mathbb{R}: c x \mapsto c$. Clearly $\lambda(x) = 1 \neq 0$. This gives you a functional on the subspace $\mathbb{R}x$ of $E$ on which you want to apply Hahn-Banach.

Consider $\mathcal{P}$ which is the set of all couples $(W, \theta)$ such that

- $W$ is a subspace of $V$
- $\mathbb{R}x \subseteq W$
- $\Vert\theta \Vert \le \Vert \lambda \Vert$
- $\theta: W \to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear functional
- $\theta\vert_{\mathbb{R}x} = \lambda$, i.e. $\theta$ extends $\lambda$.

Partially order this in the obvious way.

Applying Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal $(W, \theta)$ among those pairs.

We want to show that $W= V$, because then we have found our functional defined on all of $V$. Suppose it is not, then $W \subsetneq V$ and we can pick $y \notin W$.

The idea and the hard step in the proof is then to show that we can find a further extension $$\mu: W + \mathbb{R}y \to \mathbb{R}$$

such that $\mu$ extends $\theta$. This is what the author means with the one-dimensional extension.

The existence of such an extension will give a contradiction to the maximality of $(W, \theta)$, such that we must have had $W=V$ to begin with.

Comment: What ensures that $\mathcal{P}$ is non-empty?. And if it is, to apply Zorn's lemma, we would need the existence of an upper bound on this set, I take that the obvious way to order $\mathcal{P}$ is by inclusion in the first entry and $\leq $ on the norm of the second entry. Naturally $V$ is an upper bound on the inclusion of subspaces, but is there an upper bound in the second entry?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}$ is non-empty as it contains $(\mathbb{R}x, \lambda)$. The actual order on $\mathcal{P}$ is: $(W, \theta) \leq (W', \theta') :\iff W \subseteq W'$ and $\theta'$ extends $\theta$. Now, can you see what an upper bound for a chain $\{(W_i, \theta_i)\}_{i \in I}$ in $\mathcal{P}$ is?

Comment: Of course, that's right. Thank you. The upper bound is given by $(V,\theta_V)$, for some $(W,\theta)$ in the chain, and let $v\in V$, $\theta_V$ is defined as $v=w+u\mapsto \theta(w)$, where $w\in W$ and $u$ is a member of a complement of $W$. Is this correct?

Comment: That does not quite work, for example why does that element live in $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: Rather define $\theta_V$ by $\theta_V(v) = \theta_i(v)$ if $v \in V_i$. Why is this well-defined?

Comment: I think I finally got it. Please tell me if this is the correct reasoning. Given a chain $\{W_i,\theta_i \}_{i\in I}$ in $\mathcal{P}$, an upper bound for this chain is some $(W_{V},\theta_{V})$, where $W_V=\bigcup_{i\in I} W_i$ and $\theta_V$ is defined as you stated. Since $\{W_i \}_{i \in I}$ is a nested sequence of subspaces and the $\theta_i$ extend  $\theta_j$ for $j$ such that  $(W_i,\theta_i)\leq (W_j,\theta_j)$, then $\theta_V$ is well-defined. Now, we can apply Zorn's Lemma and prove (as you did in the main answer) that the maximal is nothing but $V$.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea!

Comment: Since you tagged with reference request, virtually any book on functional analysis has a complete proof of this theorem. Check for example: Rudin's books "Real and complex analysis", "Functional analysis", Lax' book on functional analysis, Conway's book on functional analysis. Maybe even Folland or Royden have it in their books.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is the following. Let $x \in E$. Then you want to show that there exists a continuous linear functional $f \in E^*$ s.t. $f(x) \neq 0$.

Consider the 1-dimensional linear subspace $S = \langle x \rangle$ of $E$ generated by $x$. Then we can define a linear functional on $S$ via $f(\lambda x) = \lambda$. Then we have $f$ continuous and linear with $f(x) = 1$. Now choose some $y \not\in S$ and extend $f$ to $S \oplus \langle y \rangle$ which has the same norm i.e. construct a continuous linear functional $f_1$ on $S \oplus \langle y \rangle$ s.t. $f_1 \vert_S \equiv f$ and $\Vert f_1 \Vert = \Vert f \Vert$. Then $\Vert f_1 \Vert < \infty$ and is hence continuous. Then continue this process and apply Zorn's lemma to get a continuous linear functional on all of $E$. Showing that such a functional exists is the non-trivial part of the theorem.